# Humble Indie Bundle Soundtrack - CaveStory+

Tags: cave-story

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make sense of the Cave Story+ soundtrack in the Humble Indie Bundle 4 release?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42026/how-to-make-sense-of-the-cave-story-soundtrack-in-the-humble-indie-bundle-4-rel)

I feel bad for asking this but I'm new here and couldn't comment on the previous topic found here: [How to make sense of the Cave Story+ soundtrack in the Humble Indie Bundle 4 release?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42026/how-to-make-sense-of-the-cave-story-soundtrack-in-the-humble-indie-bundle-4-rel)

I've added Wind Fortress and Halloween 2 into the mix as "Bonus" tracks. What I can't figure out is WHAT soundtrack is included in the HIB? Is it "New", "Remastered", or "Original". I'm assuming it's "New", maybe? It's hard to figure out because, well, nothing is numbered, not all the MP3s are there from the other sites, etc.

Help?

EDIT: Looks like I already answered my question. Sorry!

**"The Cave Story+ sound track included with HIB4 is a 44 track selection from this "new" sound track."**